# Pow (37signals) doesn't start at start up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, rack-pow

I am using the POW server for my rails application.  However, it doesn't start on boot.  I have to reinstall it every time.  I have tried everything in the troubleshooting guide.  Any ideas on where to look next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kicked off by a launcher script, so if that's missing or not installed you're not going to have much luck. Have you tried going through the source install process and do the [last step](https://github.com/37signals/pow/wiki/Installation):

```
launchctl load -Fw "$HOME/Library/LaunchAgents/cx.pow.powd.plist"
```

If that file is missing or not loading properly that could be your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I found a dubious permission error on my LaunchAgents directory in my syslog.  I found [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3250/why-am-i-getting-a-dubious-ownership-of-file-error-when-launch-agent-runs-my-p) and was able to fix my permissions to get it to load at boot.  The permissions were wrong for my `~/Library/LaunchAgent` directory.  It needs to be owned by me and `chmod 755`.  Files in the directory need to be own by me and `chmod 644`.